# Getting error : Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE + Hibernate 4.3.5.Final and I cannot start my application (on tomcat 6)

Error:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversIntegrator.integrate(EnversIntegrator.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1797)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1868)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 35 more
```

applicationContext :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="configLocation">
    <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springapp" />
  <property name="username" value="hibernate" />
  <property name="password" value="hib" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

One entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import springapp.service.NewRecipe;

import com.google.common.base.Strings;


@Entity
@Table
public class Recipe {

    public static final String D_ID = "id";
    public static final String D_NAME = "name";
    public static final String D_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name = D_ID) private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name = D_NAME) private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false, name = D_DESCRIPTION) private String description;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false) private Category category;


    public Recipe() {
        // for ORM
    }
}
```

One dao:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Property;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import springapp.domain.Recipe;
import springapp.service.NewRecipe;


@Repository("recipeDao")
public class HibernateRecipeDao implements RecipeDao {

    @Autowired private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public List<Recipe> getRecipes() {
        final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Recipe.class).addOrder(Property.forName(Recipe.D_ID).asc());
        final List<Recipe> recipes = criteria.list();

        return recipes;
    }
}
```

One manager :

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import springapp.domain.Recipe;
import springapp.repository.RecipeDao;


@Service("recipeManager")
public class HibernateRecipeManager implements RecipeManager {

    @Autowired private RecipeDao recipeDao;


    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<Recipe> getRecipes() {
        return recipeDao.getRecipes();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the hibernate.cfg.xml file, as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I solved this problem.

First of all Spring 3.2 **doesn't** work with Hibernate 4.3. You need to either upgrade your Spring to version 4 or **downgrade** Hibernate to version 4.2 (**4.2.11.Final** works OK for me).

Second of you cannot have **<tx:annotation-driven />** in applicationContext. You need to have it in your dispatcher context (<servlet_name>-servlet.xml). I'm not pretty sure why but here you have reference: [forum.spring.io](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/110959-hibernate4-no-session-found-for-current-thread/page2)

> Judging from your stacktrace and code you use component scanning and have duplicate components. How to overcome that is explained in the reference guide and answered many times on the forum before
>
> Aww! That's fantastic! Just moving <tx:annotation-driven/> from applicationContext to dispatcherContext and it working now! Thank's!

Comment: Hi - do you maybe have any pointers about Hibernate version compatibility with Spring 4.1.1? To solve a JPA 2.0 vs 2.1 issue, I tried downgrading hibernate from 4.3 to 4.2 - Spring did not like that, kept complaining about not finding a `org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor` service, amongst other things.